# View constrains inside Scroll View in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode6

So I added a scrollview inside a View Controller in Storyboard.
I added a single View inside the scrollview. Applied left = 0 right = 0 spacing constrains to both scrollview and the inside view.
Changed the color of scrollview and noticed that the inside view has an empty space with iPhone 6 simulator.
I have some labels aligned to the right of screen, so in iPhone 6 it will look ugly with white space in right size.

Any ideas how to fix this?